# Проблема с подключением статических файлов в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, static-content

Прохожу туториал по Django на Metanit,возникла проблема с подключением статических файлов 
HTML файл

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
    <title>Dj</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Another image</h1>
    <img src="{% static 'images/krasivo.jpg' %}" alt="Stones along the river" >
</body>
</html>
```

Вот что в файле settings.py

```
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import re_path
from firstapp import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),

]
```

Comment: а если load static прописать?

Comment: Проблему нужно угадать?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev В шапке вопроса написано,не подключаются статические файлы,не отображаются в браузере

Comment: @БогданМарченко нужно открыть DevTools и посмотреть какие адреса у статики и какие http-коды возвращаются при запросе этих адресов, а также заглянуть в логи сервера и проверить получает ли он эти запросы и как на них отвечает.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev 
`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`
`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/krasivo.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос urls.py

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[Соответствующий раздел документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development).

Comment: Я понял в чем была ошибка,нужно было вместо `STATIC_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]` добавить `STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]` только теперь вопрос,для чего нужен STATIC_DIRS?

Comment: Хм, даже не обратил внимания на это. Ни для чего не нужен, такой настройки вообще нет.

Comment: Просто он по умолчанию была в settings.py